# How to scale BitmapFontShader from skin in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, shader, font-size

This is my skin file:

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: Button-Pressed, up: Button },
    toggle: { down: Button-Pressed, checked: Button-Pressed, up: Button }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: Button-Pressed, up: Button, font: default-font, fontColor: white },
    toggle: { down: Button-Pressed, up: Button, checked: Button-Pressed, font: default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: { titleFont: default-font, background: window, titleFontColor: white },
    dialog: { titleFont: default-font, background: window, titleFontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
}
```

I changed the default-font using this code:

```
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("default.png"), true);
bitmapFontShader = new BitmapFontShader(Gdx.files.internal("default.fnt"), new TextureRegion(texture), false, 1 / 5f);

skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("myskin.json"));
skin.remove("default-font", BitmapFont.class);
skin.add("default-font", bitmapFontShader, BitmapFont.class);
```

Now I try to scale it: `skin.getFont("default-font").scale(0.5f);` and it doesn't work.
some one can tell me what could be the reason? what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try deleting following line from your skin file:
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },

Then use following code to load:

```
Skin skin=new Skin();
skin.add("default-font", bitmapFontShader);
skin.addRegions(new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("myskin.atlas")));
skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("myskin.json"));
```

Comment: what do I do about the default font in the json file? in window buttonsytle and etc'...

Comment: I believe no more change is required in json file.  Just scale with skin.getFont("default-font").scale(0.5f);  Good luck.